# How to detect devel user switch

Tags: debugging

I need to detect if I'm currently browsing the site as a different user, having used the devel user switch module.

The LDAP module I have triggers some profile updates on every login, based on some server variables set from AD/SSO. But by using devel switch, it's writing MY user details, to the profile of the person I've switched to.

I need a way of detecting it, so I can prevent the profile write.

I've had a look through the devel API [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/7) but can't see that anything is set when running as another user.

Running D7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Devel switch feature passes the login straight to the user module in [`devel_switch_user()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/devel_switch_user/7); it doesn't give other modules the chance to intervene, and doesn't provide any context that would let you know how the login has been instigated.

I guess as a simple low-tech solution you could patch that function and set a session var before it invokes the login, something like

```
...
if (!$old_uid) {
  // Switch from anonymous to authorized.
  drupal_session_regenerate();
}

$_SESSION['login_from_devel_switch'] = TRUE;

$edit = array();
user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user);
...
```

Then you can check for the existence of that session var wherever you need to prevent the profile from writing.

Comment: Seems like it would work. I'll need to check to see if hitting "logout" clears the session variable, if not I'll need to add that in too.

Comment: It does - `user_logout()` calls `session_destroy()`. Wouldn't be much of a logout if it left session vars ;)

Comment: Ha... good point! Nice simple solution then Clive, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll submit a feature request once drupal.org is back up to get this added to the devel module. I'm sure other's will find it handy!

Comment: That's a great idea. Maybe the introduction of a hook would be the best way to go? Then there's scope to do more than just set a session var - for example you could track which users are switching to who and when, and loads of other things